# Server Architecture for Embedded Device

Tags: c, linux, embedded, client-server, arm

I am working on a server application for an embedded ARM platform. The ARM board is connected to various digital IOs, ADCs, etc that the system will consistently poll. It is currently running a Linux kernel with the hardware interfaces developed as drivers. The idea is to have a client application which can connect to the embedded device and receive the sensory data as it is updated and issue commands to the device (shutdown sensor 1, restart sensor 2, etc). Assume the access to the sensory devices is done through typical ioctl.

Now my question relates to the design/architecture of this server application running on the embedded device. At first I was thinking to use something like [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), lightweight C event handling libraries. The application would prioritize the sensor polling event (and then send the information to the client after the polling is done) and process client commands as they are received (over a typical TCP socket). The server would typically have a single connection but may have up to a dozen or so, but not something like thousands of connections. Is this the best approach to designing something like this? Of the two event handling libraries I listed, is one better for embedded applications or are there any other alternatives?

The other approach under consideration is a multi-threaded application in which the sensor polling is done in a prioritized/blocking thread which reads the sensory data and each client connection is handled in separate thread. The sensory data is updated into some sort of buffer/data structure and the connection threads handle sending out the data to the client and processing client commands (I supposed you would still need an event loop of sort in these threads to monitor for incoming commands). Are there any libraries or typical packages used which facilitate designing an application like this or is this something you have to start from scratch?

How would you design what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a unix domain socket -- and write the library myself, can't see any advantages to using libvent since the application is tied to linux, and libevent is also for hundreds of connections. You can do all of what you are trying to do with a single thread in your daemon. KISS.

You don't need a dedicated master thread for priority queues you just need to write your threads so that it always processes high priority events before anything else.

In terms of libraries, you will possibly benifit from [Google's protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) (for serialization and representing your protocol) -- however it only has first class supports for C++, and the over the wire (serialization) format does a bit of simple bit shifting to numeric data. I doubt it will add any serious overhead. However an alternative is ASN.1 ([asn1c](http://lionet.info/asn1c/)).

Comment: The issue of protocols was also something I was looking into. The Google protocol buffer was actually something I came across. There is a C-only implementation also available.

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/

Comment: You would have to examine the quality of the implementation of the C library -- if C-only was high on your priority list I would take a serious look at asn.1 .

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be a modified form of your 2nd proposal.  I would create a server that has two threads.  One thread polling the sensors, and another for ALL of your client connections.  I have used in embedded devices (MIPS) [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library with great results.

A single thread that handles all sockets connections asynchronously can usually handle the load easily (of course, it depends on how many clients you have).  It would then serve the data it has on a shared buffer.  To reduce the amount and complexity of mutexes, I would create two buffers, one 'active' and another 'inactive', and a flag to indicate the current active buffer.  The polling thread would read data and put it in the inactive buffer.  When it finished and had created a 'consistent' state, it would flip the flag and swap the active and inactive buffers.  This could be done atomically and should therefore not require anything more complex than this.

This would all be *very* simple to set up since you would pretty much have only two threads that know nothing about the other.

Comment: I think this is the approach I am going to take. Is there something similar to boost::asio in C?

Comment: I don't know of anything like that, but I did some asynchronous IOs using POSIX's aio_read and friends.  I guess you could do it with aoi.h and poll/select.